# Alert dialog button doesnt give parameter to the on willPop method

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-alertdialog

I want to give parameter to the on will pop method to decide either user want to quit or not, I used methods below..

```
Future<bool> showAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
    bool response;
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      elevation: 24,
      content: Text("Çıkmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?"),
      actions: [
        TextButton(onPressed:(){
          response=true;
          return response;
          },
          child: Text("EVET")),
        TextButton(onPressed:(){
          response=false;
          return response;
          },
          child: Text("HAYIR")),
      ],
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_)=>alert);
  }
```

When the user press to the android phones back button, alert box will seen which ı shared above, according to parameter which come from this method, the app will close or not, To do that I used on will show method which seems below

```
onWillPop: ()async{
        var response = await showAlertDialog(context);
        return response;
      },
```

But when user hit "yes" or "no" nothings happen, What I do wrong, olease help me

Comment: I dont understant what you mean

Comment: change `showDialog(` to `return showDialog(`

Comment: now you are not returning any value from `showAlertDialog` function - basically you have to call `return showDialog(` at the end of `showAlertDialog` function - just for test add `print(response)` inside `onWillPop` callback and you will see what is returned now

Comment: yeah you are right I can not obtain response value but, I already changed showDialog to return showDialog,

Comment: when I print response in onWillPop nothing seen, I only changed return showDialog like use say, aside from it I use function above, but I can not obtain response value :/

Comment: you need to call `Navigator.pop(bool)` in both button callbacks

Comment: What is the difference between Navigator.pop and Navigator.of.pop

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L2566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should **return** a boolean from showDialog() function
2. Use **Navigator.of(context).pop(true);** to return true & **Navigator.of(context).pop(FALSE);** to return false on button press.

   ```
       Future<bool> showAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
        AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
          elevation: 24,
          content: Text("Çıkmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?"),
          actions: [
            TextButton(onPressed:(){
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
                child: Text("EVET")),
            TextButton(onPressed:(){

              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);

            },
                child: Text("HAYIR")),
          ],
        );
     return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_)=>alert);
      }
   ```

   .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback on the yes/no option's click action.

Here is the code..

```
typedef YesOrNoTapCallback = Function(bool);
```

Some changes in your alert dialog

```
Future showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, YesOrNoTapCallback isYesTapped) async {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      elevation: 24,
      content: Text("Çıkmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?"),
      actions: [
        TextButton(onPressed:(){

          isYesTapped(true);
        },
            child: Text("EVET")),
        TextButton(onPressed:(){

          isYesTapped(false);
        },
            child: Text("HAYIR")),
      ],
    );
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_)=>alert);
  }
```

And this is how you can use it in onWillPop

```
 onWillPop: () async {
        bool isPop = false;
        await showAlertDialog(context, (alertResponse) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(); // This will dismiss the alert dialog
          isPop = alertResponse;
        });
        return isPop;
      },
```